# passing subreport value to mainreport crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that contains a subreport. I am trying to get a value from the subreport into a field on my main report. My issue is it is not displaying on the correct report, but the report after and subsequent reports. So maybe I am not reset the var correctly.

Subreport header

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar amount := 0;
```

Subreport Footer

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar amount := {ap1.amount};
```

Mainreport formula field

```
shared numbervar amount;
amount;
```

I have the subreport in the details section ( also tried to put in report header - I am suppressing the report anyway ). Then in the details section I have the formula field which is displaying 0.00 on main report, but if I cycle through the report pages my desired value shows up on the report right after. I am linking my subreport and main report by contract no.

Any help is appreciated. Am I not declaring something right or do I need to set my shared amount to 0 somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: I ended up creating a detail section a and section b - put the subreport in section a - formula field in section b and that seemed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

On the main report formula:

shared numbervar amount;
amount := amount;